# Python; "simulate" mouse and keyboard

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, winapi, pyautogui

I recently started learning Python, trying to make short programs with simple functions but that I can use in one way or another while learning.

I have studied a bit several libraries that they functions are what the title say, with some I have had better experiences than with others, but at the moment I have a problem when trying to make a "Shift+Click" in concrete positions of the screen.

Im actually using win32api and win32con since they are the ones that to my way of seeing have better results for what Im trying to do.
Its nothing very complicated, its just do a Shift + Left Click in specific positions, like same way that you can recreate it in a normally with your mouse and keyboard.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
def mouse_click(x, y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0)
    time.sleep(0.065)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0)

def shift_down():
   win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_LSHIFT, 0, 0, 0)
   time.sleep(0.005)

def shift_up():
    win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_LSHIFT, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
    time.sleep(0.005)


def clicks():
   for offs in coord:
        x, y = offs
        x += random.randint(-15, 15)
        y += random.randint(-15, 15)
        if random.random() > 0.0:
            shift_down()
            time.sleep(0.005)
            mouse_click(x, y)
            time.sleep(0.005)
            shift_up()
            print('click on', offs)


def main():
    while True:
        if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(win32con.VK_INSERT):
            break
        elif win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(win32con.VK_F2):
            clicks()
            print('clicking end')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Yes, Im aware that some sleep are unnecessary, but here is my current problem. The way you see above is the best way I have had the code respond correctly and in time according to my needs.if I low the time on `mouse_click` below 0.55 some clicks start to be ignored, from what I have read and seen it should not be necessary make pauses, but at the moment this is the solution I found.So I want to fix the basic formatting of it first.

Am I missing something or is it some kind of "optimization" problem?

Any hints or improvements are welcome even if its about using another library.

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event) carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the PyAutoGUI module available here: https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/

It is very beginner friendly and very easy to use!

You would perform a *shift-click* like this:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.keyDown('shift')
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.keyUp('shift')
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow these randoms sleep are no longer necessary, and the sleep in `mouse_click()` I could lower it to a maximum of `0.06` without problems.

The press and release Shift seems to work fine in other applications, so I deduce that it is some kind of incompatibility with the application/window itself (Im not trying to force or use it in a particular window or screen). So maybe it can work with some other library than the ones currently in use.

The problem with the `pyautogui` and `pynput` library, is that the same thing happens but they also add some kind of delay by default.

In any case, setting the Shift press outside of `if` in `clicks()` seems to be the solution as well as using `win32con.KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY` inside `win32api.keybd_event()`.
I don't see any point in going on with this and it will probably end up being better if I hold down Shift by myself.